# How To Send Emails With Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to make a program to send emails with python, but all of the posts I found online are for python3 and over.  I have found a snippet of code that said would work on python 2.7, however when I run the script with my information, I get the error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1651176\Desktop\male2.py", line 14, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\App-V\86864BC8-DA90-464E-91D6-C9116EF05820\825D7C9B-7BA2-4F26-BDCC-55606B8D3CEC\Root\VFS\AppVPackageDrive\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 802, in __init__
    SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout)
  File "C:\ProgramData\App-V\86864BC8-DA90-464E-91D6-C9116EF05820\825D7C9B-7BA2-4F26-BDCC-55606B8D3CEC\Root\VFS\AppVPackageDrive\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\ProgramData\App-V\86864BC8-DA90-464E-91D6-C9116EF05820\825D7C9B-7BA2-4F26-BDCC-55606B8D3CEC\Root\VFS\AppVPackageDrive\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 317, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\ProgramData\App-V\86864BC8-DA90-464E-91D6-C9116EF05820\825D7C9B-7BA2-4F26-BDCC-55606B8D3CEC\Root\VFS\AppVPackageDrive\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 808, in _get_socket
    new_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(new_socket, self.keyfile, self.certfile)
  File "C:\ProgramData\App-V\86864BC8-DA90-464E-91D6-C9116EF05820\825D7C9B-7BA2-4F26-BDCC-55606B8D3CEC\Root\VFS\AppVPackageDrive\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 949, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "C:\ProgramData\App-V\86864BC8-DA90-464E-91D6-C9116EF05820\825D7C9B-7BA2-4F26-BDCC-55606B8D3CEC\Root\VFS\AppVPackageDrive\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 617, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\ProgramData\App-V\86864BC8-DA90-464E-91D6-C9116EF05820\825D7C9B-7BA2-4F26-BDCC-55606B8D3CEC\Root\VFS\AppVPackageDrive\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 846, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
SSLError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:726)
```

Is there a way to stop this error from happening?

## **My code:**

```py
import smtplib
import ssl
port = 587
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
sender_email = "send@gmail.com"  # Enter your address
receiver_email = "recieve@gmail.com"  # Enter receiver address
password = 'pwrd'
message = """\
Subject: Hi there

This message is sent from Python."""

context = ssl.create_default_context()
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context)
server.login(sender_email, password)
server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
server.quit()
```

Also:
I have tried some other code, and when I input my info, it says:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1651176\Desktop\male3o.py", line 13, in <module>
    server.login(username, password)
  File "C:\ProgramData\App-V\86864BC8-DA90-464E-91D6-C9116EF05820\825D7C9B-7BA2-4F26-BDCC-55606B8D3CEC\Root\VFS\AppVPackageDrive\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 623, in login
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, '5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at\n5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor t71-20020a37aa4a000000b00741d87eb5d1sm2863856qke.105 - gsmtp')
```

However, in google I have already generated a password for gmail and I already have 2 step verification on.   , so what is the error?

## **Other code:**

```py
import smtplib

fromaddr = 'from@gmail.com' 
toaddrs  = 'to@gmail.com'  
msg = 'This message was sent from python.'  

username = 'Username'  
password = 'pwrd'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)  
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(username, password)  
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)  
server.quit()
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you say you 'already generated a password for gmail', do you mean an application-specific password that Google provides as 'App passwords' for non-Google apps or do you mean the account password?

Comment: Yes, I went to https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords and generated an application-specific password for gmail.

Comment: You do know that Python 2.7 was [discontinued](https://peps.python.org/pep-0373/#maintenance-releases) in 2020? The sensible advice is to drop everything you're doing and upgrade to Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the code labelled Other Code, try

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


fromaddr = 'from@gmail.com' 
toaddrs  = 'to@gmail.com'  
body = 'This message was sent from python.'  

msg = MIMEText(body)
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddrs

username = 'Username'  
password = 'Password'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)  
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(username, password)  
server.sendmail(fromaddr, [toaddrs], msg.as_string())
server.close()
```

Also for `password` use the app password, `username` use normal email.